# How to get an accurate length of a long digit number in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a schema (not created by me) that has calculated variances that can be really long numbers.  I need to identify these long numbers so I can trunc them. The problem is that they are so long, the length function doesn't seem to recognize them as being long.

SELECT Length(10.00000000000000000000000000000000000004) FROM dual;

result: 2

Obviously the number above is longer than 2 digits, but the length function doesn't recognize this.  How do I get an accurate length of this number, so I can find all the cases where they exist?

Comment: Why not just around everything to three decimal digits?

Comment: try length(to_char( ....) )

Comment: That totally feels as a lossy conversion between base 10 and base 2 floating point. I'd just determine how many digits make sense in whatever magnitude they represent and round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `length()` function accepts a string as input, not a number, so the value is implicitly converted to a string using some default format before the function ever sees it.

There may be a more elegant mathematical solution, but one approach would be to use the 'text minimum' [number format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-DFB23985-2943-4C6A-96DF-DF0F664CED96), `length(to_char(num,'TM'))`:

```
with demo(num) as (select 10.00000000000000000000000000000000000004 from dual)
select to_char(num)
     , to_char(num,'TM')
     , length(to_char(num,'TM'))
from   demo;

TO_CHAR(NUM)  TO_CHAR(NUM,'TM')                         LENGTH(TO_CHAR(NUM,'TM'))
------------- ----------------------------------------- -------------------------
10            10.00000000000000000000000000000000000004                        41
```

Comment: Thanks much for the response and the explanation, this really helps me out!